# Can't login docker phpmyadmin by message #2002

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, phpmyadmin

I'm using `docker for mac` to run `laradock` and everything is alright, but the phpmyadmin can't not login by message

```
#2002 - No such file or directory &mdash; The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

Here is my `.env` file setting, and `docker-compose.yml` not change anythings

```
### PHP MY ADMIN ###
PMA_DB_ENGINE=mysql
PMA_USER=root
PMA_PASSWORD=1234
PMA_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
PMA_PORT=8080


### MYSQL ##########
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0
MYSQL_DATABASE=test
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and `$ docker-compose ps`

```
       Name                        Command               State                     Ports                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
laradock_apache2_1        /opt/docker/bin/entrypoint ...   Up       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
laradock_applications_1   /true                            Exit 0                                           
laradock_mysql_1          docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                  
laradock_php-fpm_1        docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up       9000/tcp                                
laradock_phpmyadmin_1     /run.sh phpmyadmin               Up       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                    
laradock_workspace_1      /sbin/my_init                    Up       0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp
```

Is that wrong with my login server position? or any idea?

Comment: This is oddly specific because all of the tools involved are packaged by the laradock maintainers, so tagging for phpmyadmin, docker, or mysql is unlikely to gain much assistance in this community. I suggest asking the laradock developers directly for assistance: http://laradock.io/help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe phpmyadmin is trying to connect 3306 **inside** the phpmyadmin container?

If the image for phpmyadmin is the official one you need to link with host "db"

```
--link laradock_mysql_1:db
```

or stablish the host in env variable:

```
PMA_HOST
```